# Sumsets and dilates: does $|A+\lambda A|<|A+A|$ ever hold?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, sumsets

The following problem is somehow hidden in [this recently asked question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204020/is-the-set-aaa-always-at-least-as-large-as-aa), but I believe that it deserves to be asked explicitly.

> Is it true that for any finite set $A$ of real numbers, and any real $\lambda\notin\{0,-1\}$, one has
>     $$ |A+\lambda A| \ge |A+A| $$
>   (where $\lambda A=\{\lambda a\colon a\in A\}$ is the dilate of $A$ by the factor $\lambda$, and $A+B=\{a+b\colon a\in A,\ b\in B\}$ is the sumset of $A$ and $B$)?

The energy version seems equally interesting to me. Let $T_A(\lambda)$ denote the number of representations of $\lambda$ in the form $\frac{a_1-a_2}{a_3-a_4}$ with $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\in A$. It is easily seen that $T_A(-\lambda)=T_A(\lambda)$ and $T_A(\lambda)<T_A(0)=|A|^2(|A|-1)$ for any real $\lambda\ne 0$.

> Is it true that for any finite set $A$ of real numbers, and any real $\lambda\ne 0$, one has
>     $$ T_A(\lambda) \le T_A(1) ? $$

I have not done any computations, so maybe it is possible to find a counterexample just by a computer search.

---

Both questions have now received nice and exhaustive answers thanks to Boris Bukh, Kevin Costello, and Terry Tao (who has actually answered even before the question got asked). Unfortunately, I cannot accept more than one answer; so, I am accepting only that which, for some reason, got less votes.

Comment: The answer to the second question is yes, thanks to my answer to the previous question: http://mathoverflow.net/a/204289/766

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the energy version is true if make the additional assumption that $\lambda=c/d$ is rational, meaning that $T_A(\lambda)$ counts the number of solutions in $A$ to
$$d(a_1-a_2)-c(a_3-a_4)=0 \, \, \, \, \, \, (*).$$  Using a Freiman isomorphism together with translation invariance, we can assume that $A$ is a subset of integers lying in $[0,n]$.

Let $p$ be a prime larger than $2(c+d)n$.  We now think of $A$ as a subset of $Z_p$, which does not change the solution count.  Let $f$ be the characteristic function of $A$, and $\hat{f}$ its Fourier transform.  The number of solutions to $(*)$ is then given by
$$\sum_{\xi \in Z_p} \hat{f}(d \xi) \hat {f} (-d \xi) \hat{f}(c \xi) \hat{f}(-c \xi)=\sum_{\xi \in Z_p} |\hat{f} (d \xi)|^2 |\hat{f} (c \xi)|^2$$

Since $c$ and $d$ are nonzero, the two sequences $|\hat{f} (d \xi)|^2$ and $|\hat{f} (c \xi)|^2$ are permutations of each other.  So it follows from the [rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) that the sum is maximized when $c=d$, which corresponds to $\lambda=1$.

It seems intuitive that moving from the rational to the reals can't increase the number of solutions, but I don't see an obvious way of extending this.

Answer (score 13):

It is false. Let $\lambda$ be any integer other than $0$ and $\pm 1$. First, I will construct an example mod $p$ for every large prime $p$, which will then be upgraded to $\mathbb{Z}$ by taking Cartesian products.

For each pair $\{a,a'\}$ satisfying $a+\lambda a'=0$ toss a coin, which decides which element is "eliminated". (Note that there is no rule against double jeopardy!). Let $A$ be the set of surviving elements. It is clear that $0\not\in A+\lambda A$. On the other hand, $A+A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with high probability. Indeed, fix $x$ and consider the event $x\in A+A$. We can easily find linearly many pairs $\{a,x-a\}$ such that the sets of coin tosses on which they depend are disjoint. So, $\Pr[x\not\in A+A]=O(c^{-p})$ and the union bound completes the argument modulo $p$.

Let $p_1,p_2,\dotsc$ be distinct primes and let $A_{p_1},A_{p_2},\dotsc$ be the sets modulo these primes such that $0\not \in A+\lambda A$, but $A+A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Let $P=\prod p_i$ and $P'=\prod (p_i-1)$. Let $A=A_{p_1}\times A_{p_2}\times \dotsb A_{p_k}\subset \mathbb{Z}/P\mathbb{Z}$ (I am using the Chinese Remainder theorem). Then $|A+A|=P$ and $|A+\lambda A|\leq P'$. Since the sum of reciprocals of the primes diverges, we can make the ratio $P/P'$ as large as we wish, and in particular larger than $|\lambda|+1$. If we then treat $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, then the size of $A+\lambda A$ can be at most $(|\lambda|+1)P'$ which is still smaller than $P$.

A similar argument ought to give a counterexample for algebraic values of $\lambda$, but I have not worked out the details.